Export to XLSX or convert CSV to XLSX
I'm trying to export data to .xlsx via T-SQL. I changed the script to .xlsx and the file is corrupted.
Is there a way directly export to .xlsx or use a .csv file and convert it to .xlsx via SQL script?
SET @BcpStatement = 'bcp "' + @SqlStatement + '" queryout "' + @ExportFileName + '" -t"," -c -T'


I guess bcp can only to text file export.

excel can import csv files

just need to replicate a process, they drop xlsx files that were manually created, just matching the process, I can always run something else on top, just wanted to use one process to replicate

T-SQL and BCP are the wrong tools for this. Use something else. SSIS, Powershell, C#, are just a few examples of alternatives.

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..##TABELA') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##TABELA

CREATE TABLE dbo.##TABELA 
(
 ID     INT
,NAME   VARCHAR(100)
,CITY   VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO ##TABELA
values 
(1, 'NAME 01', 'CITY 01')
,(1, 'NAME 02', 'CITY 02')
,(1, 'NAME 03', 'CITY 03')
,(1, 'NAME 04', 'CITY 04')

DECLARE @SERVIDOR VARCHAR(50)    
DECLARE @CAMINHO VARCHAR(500)    
SET @SERVIDOR = (SELECT @@SERVERNAME)        
SET @CAMINHO = 'D:\TEMP\'        

exec
('XP_CMDSHELL  ''BCP "SELECT * from ##TABELA" QUERYOUT '+@CAMINHO+'RELATORIO.CSV -c -t; -T -C RAW -S '+@SERVIDOR+'''')        


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
